# A diptych is a pair of paintings. What is a single painting called?

Tags: latin, terminology

A [diptych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diptych) (from the Greek di "two" and ptychē "fold") is a pair of paitings. You can also say triptych for a group of three paintings belonging together, septych for a group of seven and so on. Polyptych is an umbrella term for these words.

**Is there a word for a single painting that has similar etymology?**

**If not, is there a word for a single work of art that can be used when one wants to emphasize that it's a single independent work of art, as opposed to a part of a group (for example a diptych)?**

Comment: I would call it a tablet (or perhaps a plaque if it was fixed to a wall).  Given that a single panel is not folded then it makes little sense to add the suffix 'ptych'

Comment: I think you have invalidated my answer with your edit. That is not A Good Thing To Do.

Comment: wouldn't a group of seven more properly be a heptatych or something along those lines?

Comment: @AndrewLeach The original question is still there, I just added a follow up question, and you kind of already answered that as well as possible with "panel", so your answer is very valid.

Comment: @sumelic It's a bit odd but I think **septych** is the correct term. For some reason it uses the Latin **septem** (seven). You'll have to ask someone else why :)

Comment: @sumelic I think it comes down to ignorance of the Greek *hepta-* form. The middle *p* is part of *ptych,* so even the Latinate hybrid should be *septaptych.* The word *heptaptych* does appear in the Wikipedia article on [*polyptych.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyptych)

Comment: "Google"? (Since most people don't bother looking "below the fold".)

Comment: It’s a **tiptych**, because without the support of a second or third panel, it tips over. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The etymology of *diptych* and its extensions *triptych* and *polyptych* includes the concept of the folding of the images.

> Mid 19th century: from late Latin *polyptycha* (neuter plural) 'registers', from Greek *poluptukhos* 'having many folds', from *polu-* 'many' + *ptukhē* 'fold'.
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polyptych)

As Chasly  has commented, the concept of folding a single panel is rather self-defeating, so *monoptych,* which would be etymologically correct, is not found.

Generally, as the linked paintings are painted on board, the term *panel* is used.

Comment: You're right about _monotych_ being self-defeating. _Panel_ could be used, but it would be interesting to find a word that emphasizes that it's a single stand-alone painting as contrary to a diptych. I'll update the question asking for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the "ptych" concept doesn't really apply to a single piece, but if I wanted to name it that way to clarify it differing from other, multi-part, pieces of art, I would be inclined to call it a holoptych, indicating that it's both singular and that the one item is the whole of the art piece.